# asp:DropDownList get selected value from database was inserted before

Tags: sql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to get a value from database and put it into a `DropDownList` as selected value, so when I want to edit this user I get their older department for example.

Someone works in department 1 and now I want to update their department to 2. But I want the `DropDownList` to auto select their older department 1 from the database so if I want to keep it I get the same older value without changes.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="departmentvalue" DataValueField="departmentvalue" CssClass="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True" ID="department"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>شئون العاملين</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>تكنولوجيا المعلومات</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>السكرتاريه</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>الامن</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>معمل الابحاث</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>الجوده</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>الانتاج</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>عنبر الخلط</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>المخازن</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>الامن الصناعى</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>المطعم</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>البوفيه</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>خدمات</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

When I added ID it says error but works fine and gives the result but it does not give the value when I click save, it keeps the value empty.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand the issue, but maybe you need to add the property AppendDataBoundItems="true" to the control?

Comment: also are you doing anything to this control in page load event?